# How to extract table as an indipendente component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I used `react-bootstrap-table` lib to show tables, and I used a lot (about 10 times ) tables in my project, they all have common options like `exportCSV search clearSearch` ecc. It makes sense to create a common components (tags) to centralize the `BootstrapTable` and `TableHeaderColumn` tag.

I want the following code

```
    <BootstrapTable data={slotListVM}  exportCSV search options={options}>
                <TableHeaderColumn dataField="id" width="150" dataSort>ID</TableHeaderColumn
    </BootstrapTable>
```

become

```
    <Table data={slotListVM}>
                <TableColumn dataField="id">ID</TableColumn>
    </Table>
```

Is it possible? (I tried, but got `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined    at BootstrapTable.initTable` error)

PS: I thought about to centralize the table as a component by pass all the column data,
like

```
    <Table data={slotListVM} colume1={'id'} colume2={'name'}>
    </Table>
```

but I think

```
    <Table data={slotListVM}>
                <TableColumn dataField="id">ID</TableColumn>
    </Table>
```

is a better solution.

Could someone give me some suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about wrapping `react-bootstrap-table` lib components - `BootstrapTable` and `TableHeaderColumn` into your own stateless functional components, e.g.:

```
const Table = ({data, options, children} => (
  <BootstrapTable data={data} options={options} exportCSV search>
    {children}
  </BootstrapTable>
)
```

same for `TableColumn`:

```
const TableColumn = ({dataField, children} => (
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={dataField} width="150" dataSort>
    {children}
  </TableHeaderColumn>
)
```

You can read more about it here:

https://javascriptplayground.com/functional-stateless-components-react/
https://hackernoon.com/react-stateless-functional-components-nine-wins-you-might-have-overlooked-997b0d933dbc